# how is an IOS App Group entitlement added to an Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

My Xamarin.IOS project will write a file to a shared folder and is configured for my App Group.
My Xcode ObjC project needs to read this file, but I can't figure out how to configure it for the same App Group entitlement.

I went to my Apple Developer account and added the App Group to be shared by both projects, and also App ID's for both projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

Xcode proj > TARGETS > (my proj) > + Capabilities > double-click App Group

Would be nice if Xcode had a search command to find an item amid their 100's of configuration items.